# Microsoft Interop Excel: Write Data on next print-page

Tags: .net, excel, interop

I want to write two DataSets into an Excel-Sheet like this

```
DATASET1
HEADER1 | HEADER2 | HEADER3 | ... |
========|=========|=========|======
DATA11  | DATA12  | DATA13  | ... |
           ...

DATASET2
HEADER1 | HEADER2 | HEADER3 | ... |
========|=========|=========|======
DATA11  | DATA12  | DATA13  | ... |
          ...
```

Well in fact this isn't a difficult task because you can simply iterate through the datasets and need make sure that your pointers are correct. But now I want to ensure that the second Dataset's title and data will be in the *next print page area* to ensure that title and data are on the same page (eg create a PDF-File out of it).

In Word/LaTeX are commands/macros to initiate a page-break. Is there something similar in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply use `Sheet.HPageBreaks.Add` method. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821334(v=office.15).aspx).

The best way to learn how to do all this stuff with Excel is to record macros; the best tool ever.

Your approach still seems a bit off though. What guarantees do you have that each table will fit vertically or horizontally in one page? Maybe you'd be better off exporting each table into its own sheet and forcing it to print in one sinlge page. Another option, if tables can span multiple pages, is to configure each sheet so that the headers are printed at the top of every page.

To learn how to implement any of these options, record a macro and do it manually.

Comment: Oh okay I know what you mean. But the given table-design above was just an example. The Table is limited in columns but not in rows. That's why I asked for a way to do a pagebreak. Thanks for the help